# Classic ASP - Stored Procedure Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I've written a stored procedure ("UpdateTable") that takes one parameter and inserts a new row into a table when run.

I've got the following code in an asp page:-

```
dim conn
dim cmd

set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Persist Security Info=False;Password=password;User ID=username;Initial Catalog=SQLLearning"

set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "UpdateTable"
cmd.CommandType =adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Text",adVarChar,adParamInput, 100)

cmd("Text") = "Jessica"
cmd.Execute
```

When I run this I get the following error:-

**ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'**

**Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.**

**/sp.asp, line 14**

Where line 14 is the `cmd.CommandType =adCmdStoredProc` line.  I've tried numerous things, including declaring a constant called adCmdStoredProc with the value of 4, and this still doesn't work.  Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

The 'UpdateTable' code is:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateTable
    @Text varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO StoredProcTest (Text)
    OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Text
    VALUES (@Text)
END
GO
```

Comment: paste the `UpdateTable` procedure

Comment: One more suggestion; in your stored proc this line `INSERT INTO StoredProcTest (Text)` here `Text` is a reserve word. Try escaping it saying `INSERT INTO StoredProcTest ([Text])`

Comment: Might be silly, but try having `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn` i.e. add "Set", since it's an object trying to set it without the "Set" might cause weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "UpdateTable"

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Text",adVarChar,adParamInput, 100)
        .Parameters("@Text") = "Jessica"
        set rs = .Execute
    End With
set cmd = nothing
```

You should then be able to get the result doing something similar to;

```
if not rs.eof then
    response.write rs("ID")
end if
```

Comment: What's with the extra indent on the `With`? Plus why bother with `ADODB.Connection` when you can pass the connection string directly to `ADODDB.Command`.`ActiveConnection` property? That way the connection is instantiated with the `Execute()` method and disposed when the command object is released from memory.

Comment: The extra indent on the `With` is purely a coding style - personally I find it easier to read. Could you clarify what you mean in the second part of your comment please, as I haven't used `ADODB.Connection` in my example, unless you mean the `conn` object? In my scripts this is an object created in a header include and destroyed in a footer include - again purely a personal coding style.

Comment: Actually, @Albofish, using the `ADODB.Connection` like that isn't ideal, as it defeats the ability of the connection pool to handle things; you're locking up a connection for time when it's not being used. It's best to open it as late as possible and close it as early as possible. As for the indentation on the `With`, you are exactly right there; there's no functional difference.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks, I never knew that.